# Take last N commits of the current branch and apply them to another branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

This is my scenario:

- I'm in the `master` branch
- From the `master` branch, the branch `feature1` was created
- Several commits were added to `feature1` and other commits were added to `master`
- Now, I want to take **ONLY** the last N commits from `feature1` and apply them to `master`.

I want to go from this:

```
                       (branch) feature1: f1 > f2 > f3 > f4
                      /
(branch) master: A > B > C > D
```

To this:

```
                       (branch) feature1:  f1 > f2 > f3 > f4
                      /
(branch) master: A > B > C > D > f3 > f4
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can observe last hashes of your commits by running

`git log -N` where N is number of commit hashes you want to see.

and then you can do

`git cherry-pick {firstHash}^..{lastHash}` where `{firstHash}` and `{secondHash}` are starting point and ending point of your cherry-picking , its like closed interval [firstHash,lastHash] , so all commits in between will be taken as well.

**Note:** `firstHash` has to come before `lastHash` for obvious reasons.

if you don't want them to be commited and you only want the content of them you can do

`git cherry-pick {firstHash}^..{lastHash} --no-commit`

In your case if we consider (f1,f2..) are commit hashes, this should do the drill:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick f3^..f4
```

If there are any merge conflicts you gonna have to resolve them and call `git cherry-pick --continue` (sometimes git bash is stubborn about it and it doesn't show you that) to be able to continue onto the next commit.

In any case you should check the documentation of cherry pick as @Erhan mentioned - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: It worked! By using `--no-commit`, `cherry-pick` combines all the commits from `feature1` in a single one and adds it to the top of `master`. If not using `--no-commit`, all commits are added on top of `master`, along with the merge commits.

Comment: `git cherry-pick -N branch_name` has also worked for me to cherry-pick the top `N` commits from the branch_name.

Comment: @Hi-Angel awesome, it saves my life.

Answer (score -1):

you can cherry pick selective commits onto master:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick